# Import Data into Cloud SQL Using Cloud SQL Client Connection Ended

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, mysql-workbench, google-cloud-sql, cloud-sql-proxy

I am trying to run a SQL script from MySQL workbench, and have it import data to Cloud SQL using Cloud SQL Client proxy. This SQL script is about 10 GB. I have tried this a few times, and it takes too long, and says the certification of the connection will expire soon. Soon after that, the so the connection ends, and I see an error on workbench saying lost connection to MySQL server.

Are there any suggestions on what I should do / do different?
I am not wanting to use Cloud SQL Buckets to import data, and hence am going the route of Cloud SQL Client.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection ended error can be due to many different reasons. One being your script is too large and is causing the connection to timeout. I would suggest splitting your script and importing them separately.

It is possible that the “certification of the connection will expire soon” error can be resolved by rotating your server certificates. You can find how to do that here: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/manage-ssl-instance#manage-server-certs